# Restoring apps from TWRP

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, custom-roms, twrp, miui

I have a backup of my previous `MIUI` ROM(using TWRP), and presently, I am on  custom ROM called `cyonogenmod`. Now, I need to restore my previous user apps(apps that are installed from Play Store) and its data that run on MIUI to new ROM. How can it be done? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It can be done with  Titanium Backup, see [titanium-backup](/questions/tagged/titanium-backup) tag for more details.
  From Main Menu of app access *Extract from Titanium Backup* option and you would be able to choose the apps which you can restore. This is fine if you are talking of third party apps
- *File-carving* technologies on the Nandroid images (see our [data-recovery](/questions/tagged/data-recovery) [tag-wiki] would also do this ( I am not conversant with this ). You can read more here [Are there any downsides to using a nandroid recovery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/129547/131553). Also see this for other possibilities [Restore only part of nandroid image](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7851/131553)

Comment: I don't need system apps to be restored, other applications  which I have installed using play store

Comment: In which case first two bullet points answer your question

Comment: Simplest would be Titanium Backup option but it takes some time for it to read the Nandroid backup

Comment: Whether, I need to be in pro version of Titanium backup?

Comment: I don't recall, sorry, I always used the pro version. You can try- of it is supported only in pro version, then try the second bullet option

Comment: Can you please share if it worked for you?

Comment: Sorry. I have restored back previous stable version using TWRP itself.

Comment: That obvious solution was not included in the answer for a good reason - you could run into problems since what is *installed* app on one device could be  *system* app on another device / ROM as per your question. That is a risky option and only safe options were presented. BTW, I hope you took care *not* to restore / EFS , your IMEI could be messed up, if you did